# MySQL C++ connector program throws error 15

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012, connector

My simple mysql c++ connector program is throwing error 15. What does this mean? The code was taken directly from the online documentation. I can't find the error codes documented anywhere. It's strange because the data ends up getting inserted into the table . Yes i know my statements should be parameterized to avoid SQL injection , this is just a simple test program.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream> 

/* 
Include directly the different 
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h 
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time! 
*/ 
#include "mysql_connection.h" 

#include <cppconn/driver.h> 
#include <cppconn/exception.h> 
#include <cppconn/resultset.h> 
#include <cppconn/statement.h> 

using namespace std; 

int main(void) 
{ 
try { 
sql::Driver *driver; 
sql::Connection *con; 
sql::Statement *stmt; 
sql::ResultSet *res; 

/* Create a connection */ 
driver = get_driver_instance(); 
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "1092Wilda"); 
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */ 
con->setSchema("test"); 

stmt = con->createStatement(); 
res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO bung VALUES ('39', 'TestVal')"); 
delete res; 
delete stmt; 
delete con; 

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) { 
cout << e.getErrorCode(); 
} 

cout << endl; 

return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: you've got a lot going on in that try block. narrow down WHICH of those sql statements is causing the problem. e.g. if the connection's failing because your mysql has TCP disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging around in the header file statement.h i found out that there was a function called executeUpdate (function header below)

```
virtual int executeUpdate(const sql::SQLString& sql) = 0;
```

this ended up doing what i wanted to do. program added values into database without throwing any exceptions.

i wish the mySQL C++ connector library wasn't so poorly documented.